# importing CSV file prestashop 1.6

Tags: prestashop-1.6

I'm new with prestashop and I have an issue with importing product CSV file, especialy with the name field. it dosn't take the value of this field so i get errors every time i tried to import the file.
exemple :
`ID;Active (0/1);name;Categories (x,y,z...)
100;1;Pyjama long avec haut rayé imprimé - Taupe;PYJAMA FEMME`

but when I try this it work fine ::

```
ID;Active (0/1);nom;Categories (x,y,z...)
100;1;aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa;PYJAMA FEMME
```

HELP PLEASE

Comment: I found out that the problems is with 'éçà' when i remove this caracters it works fine.now I need to know how to replace this caracters

Answer (score -1):

I found the answer.I had to choose 'Fichier encodé en ISO-8859-1' :OUI